# Open Source ebook reader

Tags: open-source

I have an idea for some interesting features in an ebook reader, but don't want to spend time building the basic ebook viewer. Is there any open source ebook reader (that works on mobile/tablet/laptop) that can easily be plugged in.

It would be great if it had APIs for functions like:

1. The page number where the user stopped reading
2. Book meta-data like title, author, genre and total length of the book.
3. Collection of books in the users library

Comment: [SumatraPdf](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the Readium SDK project: http://readium.org/projects/readium-sdk
It's supposed to be a rendering engine for creating EPUB3-compliant reading apps, but it's not complete yet.

Comment: futurepress/epub.js reads epub and allow annotation through a web browner.